# Why does a .DS_Store file keep appearing on the desktop?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, desktop

Every time I delete it from the desktop, I get the same file ".DS_store" created after some time. Is there a reason why this happens ? And can I permanently stop it from being created ?

Comment: See the [Wikipedia entry on .DS_Store](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store) which explains what the file does. In short, Finder writes one in each folder to track icon locations, sized and the last window position / sort / size so you see a folder the way it was next time you open it. Desktop is always visible, hence the constant recreation of this file by the Finder.

Comment: Have you ruled out disk corruption by booting to the recovery HD and running a disk repair operation? I would also get a good backup before poking at it in any way in case it's a sign of pending disk subsystem failure. Not likely, but why risk it if you don't have regular backups.

Comment: @Alex so theres no way to hide that particular file type ??

Comment: @bmike my laptop is about 2 months old, I really hope its not a pending disk subsystem failure already !!!

Comment: @Fendi, see [this Superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/31580/show-hidden-files-on-os-x-except-ds-store) question as well.

Comment: @Alex thank you .. Sadly I will have to either live with it or just hide everything...

Comment: @Fendi On Windows I always wanted to see the hidden files, but I left this habit behind after switching to Mac.

Comment: @Alex aren't there disadvantages of not viewing hidden files ?

Comment: @fendi - the vast majority of failures happen in the first week to month of use. It's more likely corruption which is just a random occurrence - bad luck but a reinstall fixes it and you're not likely to have problems going forward.

Comment: @bmike can you please explain or point me to an article that mentions how the appearance of .DS_Store in the desktop might be related to a possible disk failure ?

Comment: @Fendi I haven’t found one. However, if you need to see them, you can either use [this](http://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/developer/hiddenfiles.html) widget or just fire Terminal and use `ls -la` in the respective folder.

Comment: Over 3 years later and still no further to being able to exclude `.htaccess` files from being hidden without showing all hidden (dot) files.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Type this in Terminal (/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app):

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE
killall Finder
```

The first command sets the hidden files visibility to hidden; the second one forces Finder to restart. This is needed for the first command to take effect.

You can also log out/reboot instead of killing the Finder, but the first command is needed to change a hidden preference (one that the Finder can’t change using the normal Finder view options or preferences).

Comment: Would like an explanation please

Comment: The answerer is guessing that your finder somehow was set to show hidden files. It is the most logical explanation for why a file that normally is hidden by Finder would show, but you would also expect to see .DS_Store files _everywhere_ if this were the case.

Comment: @Fendi The first command sets the hidden files visibility to hidden; the second one forces Finder to restart, action that is needed in order to make it take in consideration the previous command.

Comment: Guess the only way to do it is to hide the hidden files or live with it ..

Comment: Just to keep this thread up to date, it's no longer necessary to kill the Finder to show/hide dot files. I'll post a new answer with a simple Applescript.

Comment: This hides dotfiles *everywhere*, not just on the desktop. There's a legitimate use case for being able to view and work with dotfiles, but not having a useless icon permanently displayed on the desktop.

Comment: -1 Not only does this hide dot files everywhere, as mentioned, it also hides **all** dot files - which might not be advisable if the user has hidden files visible enabled in the first place.

Comment: @kontur I'd imagine the OP to know what .DS_Stores are if they were to know how to enable/disable hidden files.

Comment: @duci9y sure, but that doesn't change the assumption that she might actually want dot files showing, just not that particular one. Following that logic, the answer will have the undesirable effect of hiding dot files everywhere.

Answer (score 15):

There's a way to hide all "dot" files from Desktop with 3rd party app called [XtraFinder](https://www.trankynam.com/xtrafinder/).

Go to Settings → Features tab → Hide dot files on Desktop

[image: Screenshot of XtraFinder]

Though I still didn't manage to hide all `.DS_Store` files and keep all other dot files visible, this is a pleasant improvement.

Comment: Most developers want dot files to show, so the first answer (which has also been marked accepted) isn't helpful. The initial question is about hiding the dot files on the desktop and this answer solves this problem - thank you @micer +1

Comment: @alexkb I use [tinkerTool](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html) for showing system files, but also tried adding XtraFinder to hide the .DS_Store file from desktop (and other hidden files which, on desktop, I don't want) - this way you can still have dot files displayed, just not on desktop.

Answer (score 5):

.DS_Store is used by OS X to store directory information used by Finder such as icon position, etc.

In OS X any file name that starts with a "." is hidden, so to hide the .DS_Store file you can use the terminal command:

```
sudo defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles NO
```

Basically, you can ignore it.  If you are copying a directory to a flash drive and looking at it in Windows, feel free to just delete it.  It is Mac OS X Finder that creates this file whenever it opens a new directory.

An alternative solution would be to prevent Finder from automatically creating these files.  The following terminal command changes the default setting from automatically creating them to not:

```
defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores TRUE
```

And to revert back to the default behavior:

```
defaults delete com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores
```

Comment: The second option to prevent .DS_Store works for network drives only.  It has no effect for the local drive unfortunately.  Finder still loves its .DS_Store files.

Answer (score 5):

For those who would like to still view other hidden files but hide the desktop .DS_Store file, the solution is to give the desktop version a transparent icon. The best instructions I have found are here:

https://www.scottofford.com/2013/03/hide-ds-store-on-mac/

When finished with the transparent icon, drag the icon's text to off the screen and you will never see the desktop file again.

Comment: Just drag the icon's text off the screen and you will not see the text. Regardless if it is a cheat or not @atilkan, I have found it to accomplish my needs better than any other suggestion on here at this point. I actually forgot that the file was still on my desktop until I saw your comment, LOL.

Comment: I didn't realize this game had rules. :) Totally useful to me.

Comment: Been using this hack for 3 yrs, its at the bottom corner with text hidden, very useful imho

Answer (score 0):

Just to keep this thread up to date, it's no longer necessary to kill the Finder to show/hide dot files.

This Applescript will do it by refreshing all window contents instead; it's also faster than relaunching the Finder.

```
set newHiddenVisiblesState to "YES"
try
    set oldHiddenVisiblesState to do shell script "defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles"
    if oldHiddenVisiblesState is in {"1", "YES"} then
        set newHiddenVisiblesState to "NO"
    end if
end try
do shell script "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles " & newHiddenVisiblesState


tell application "Finder"
    set theWindows to every Finder window
    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in theWindows
        set this_item to item i of theWindows
        set theView to current view of this_item
        if theView is list view then
            set current view of this_item to icon view
        else
            set current view of this_item to list view

        end if
        set current view of this_item to theView
    end repeat
end tell
```

Save as an app & launch to toggle visibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can Remove all DS_Store files

1. Select Applications > Utilities to launch Terminal.
2. Enter the following UNIX command:
3. sudo find / -name ".DS_Store" -depth -exec rm {} \;

When prompted for a password enter your Mac OS X Administrator password.

You can also schedule a crontab to remove them periodically 
More details: https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/kb/remove-ds-store-files-mac.html

Answer (score 0):

> And can I permanently stop it from being created ?

> Over 3 years later and still no further to being able to exclude
> .htaccess files from being hidden without showing all hidden (dot)
> files.

This answer comes a little late, but I've stumbled across this question, and I believe I have a useful solution: you could just *disable* the `.DS_store` creation in the first place. [Death to .DS_Store](https://www.aorensoftware.com/blog/2011/12/24/death-to-ds_store/) explains one way how. I have tested this on 10.5, 10.6, and 10.15.

```
brew install deathtodsstore
```

This installs a handy GUI application, check "Launch Agent Installed" and "Patch Finder". (I think you have problems with re-opening windows on log-in in 10.15.) However, as documented, still, this will not work with [SIP](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/disabling_and_enabling_system_integrity_protection) on; specifically (from experimentation,) `csrutil disable; csrutil enable --without fs --without debug` (this is undocumented and probably not manufacturer approved.) However, with this, [hiding files](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/234327/unhide-invisible-files-from-the-command-line) behave much more as expected.

Answer (score -2):

There is an application you can download called Show Hidden Files.app
It allows you to easily toggle hidden files on and off.  The .ds store file is always generated in finder.  You can only hide the file through the methods mentioned, or with this handy script.

Answer (score -3):

You can just download and use an [app to remove ds_store files](http://annoyingfilebegone.typhoonsoftware.com) from the Apple App Store.

Comment: That's for external & non-HFS+ formatted drives, not internal.

Answer (score -4):

Apparently, it was due to an old Safari update that accidentally showed the .DS_Store file.