# Unhide invisible files from the command line

Tags: terminal, finder, command-line, macos

By default, a number of system directories (such as ~/Library) are hidden in OS X (ie. they don't appear in Finder):

[image: Library Folder]

I know I can do this through the GUI but I would like to add a script to my [dotfiles](https://dotfiles.github.io/) that does this automatically for certain system directories.

Is it possible to remove the hidden flag for a file/directory from the command line?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### For files hidden by prepended `.`

To show:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES; killall Finder
```

To hide:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles NO; killall Finder
```

*edit: as per RikerW's advice, to shorten these long strings into some shorter strings, add the following line to `~/.bash_profile` from your favorite text editor:*

```
alias showall='defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES; killall Finder'
alias hideall='defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles NO; killall Finder'
```

*do note that you will have to do `source ~/.bash_profile` to update your shell with the new aliases.*

---

### For files hidden from the GUI:

To show:

```
sudo chflags nohidden /path/to/file
```

To hide:

```
sudo chflags hidden /path/to/file
```

Do bear in mind that this completely removes the `hidden` flag.

Comment: Excellent, I was looking for the latter, but the first option is also good to know. Not sure if the ```sudo``` is strictly necessary though.

Comment: It depends, really. `chflags` works if you're the owner of the file, and if you're not, then `sudo` is necessary.

Comment: Would have accepted anyway, just needed to wait for the 10 minute lag to pass. Don't have enough reputation to upvote yet.

Comment: Also note, adding a alias to `.bash_profile` is generally a good idea.  I have `showall` and `hideall` set to hide/show dotfiles.

Comment: I ran into a case where `chflags nohidden` didn't work, but what did work was `xattr -c /path/to/file`.  It was the Finder info extended attribute that was hiding the file.

Comment: @JWWalker Thank you! Your `xattr -rc /path/to/folder/*` (changing all hidden files & folders) is what ended up working for me on my MacBook Pro  Mojave 10.14.2 `chflags` wasn't working.