# How do I access "hidden" .help files

Tags: finder, macos

Some years ago I created a Project (using Xcode 3 under OS X 10.6) and created a Help File, naming this `MyApp.help` in accordance with the tutorial.

Under more recent OS Apple (in its infinite wisdom) decided to make all `.help` files packages and not display contents. You could still see the contents in `Finder` with `Show Package Contents`.

In `El Capitan` the contents of `.help` files seems to be hidden, but seemingly not in the fashion that was previously used to hide files such as `~/Library`.
(It is still possible to display Package Contents in the finished `.app` to see these, so the intent does not seem to be to hide these from the end user.)

How do you get access to these files to modify contents and/or add new files? They are still there, and can be seen in the `Terminal`. `cd PathToMyApp/MyApp.help/Contents/Resources`

Edit 
I was exploring the suggestions, without much success. After some trials I rebooted and could no longer see the files in `Terminal`.

I have a backup to an external HDD (using `rsync`) and could see all the files when mounted on Linux. (I can also load and edit in `BBEdit` through a Project).

I just tried again and they were all back in `Terminal`.

Comment: Are you saying that if you use the commands `ls -a` or `ls -la`, these files do not appear?

Comment: To modify the Finder to show hidden files, try the solution I posted [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/186376/hotkey-to-show-hidden-files-and-folders-in-file-open-dialog/186388#186388).

Comment: @DavidAnderson No I can see the files in the Terminal using the command line, but not in Finder (or other apps which use normal dialog boxes).

Comment: Alternatively, have a look at this answer I posted over [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/234328/162909) which covers files hidden by prepended `.` and `chflags`.

Comment: For other apps which use normal dialog boxes, try [this solution](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/186376/hotkey-to-show-hidden-files-and-folders-in-file-open-dialog/186378#186378)

Comment: Doesn't show package contents on the .help folder work? i.e. not just on the .app folder

Answer (score 1):

I think I have solved my problem.

In `Terminal` I used `chflags nohidden` on the `.help` file and all the files now appear in `Finder`